# Second elevation dialog

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a simple application in which i'm installing an exe and running it at the end of the installation. But when installation is finished it shows second elevation dialog for app.exe which i don't want it to show, here is my wix code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!-- The following three sections are from the How To: Add a File to Your Installer topic-->
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="My Application Name"/>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

<DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY">
  <Component Id="app.exe" Guid="12345678-1234-1234-1234-222222222223">
    <File Id="app.exe" Source="MySourceFiles\app.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
<Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="app.exe" />
</Feature>
<!-- Step 2: Add UI to your installer / Step 4: Trigger the custom action -->
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='LaunchInstalledExe' After='InstallFinalize'/>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>

  <CustomAction Id="LaunchInstalledExe"
     FileKey="app.exe"

     ExeCommand=""
     Return="ignore" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That executable is being run after InstallFinalize, so it's not going to be elevated by default, and it apparently has an elevation manifest so it will ask for elevation. I would try before InstallFinalize (and not immediate) to see if that fixes the problem, and you probably want it impersonated too. After InstallFinalize is the safer place. The issue is that an admin could launch the install (or push it out via group policy) and walk away, leaving a limited user having access to a program running elevated that could do things a limited user should not be allowed to do. I certainly wouldn't want an install to be launched for a limited user that later results in that user having access to a program that can configure database security, for example. So the elevation prompt resulting from after InstallFinalize is appropriate from the security point of view. But it all depends on your clients and their environment and the product itself.